# mapping error in verilog

Tags: system-verilog, xilinx-ise

I'm constantly getting this error in my mapping process in Xilinx 8bit processor verilog code: 
" The design is too large to fit the device." 
 and 
"ERROR:Pack:2309 - Too many bonded comps of type "IOB" found to fit this device."
 I have Xilinx 14.7 installed on my system,how do I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you have more top-level ports than the FPGA device has. You should reduce the number of ports. If you cannot, you will need a larger FPGA.

If you don't really need to interface the FPGA ports, you may create a wrapper module and XOR all your outputs, then may assign only the 1-bit output to a port. This method is suggested on [Xilinx Forums](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Implementation/pack-2309-error-in-xilinx-ise-12-4/td-p/561872) as well.